# Is there a way to trigger the menu in Play Books without a menu button?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-one-x, google-play-books

On my HTC One X there is no menu button.  Once I have selected a book and started reading all the menus disappear (for changing font size or scrolling through the book), the only way I can get them to re-appear is to switch out of the Play Books application and then switch back, the menu then appears for a few seconds.  Is there an easier way to trigger the menu to appear when I don't have a menu button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tap anywhere on the page and the menu reappears.